# Why am I getting an NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Tags: android, soap

When I make a service call from my Android activity, I see an `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Why?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11934474/networkonmainthreadexception-while-i-see-if-i-have-internet-connection/11934508#11934508 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Answer (score 0):

You should perform any service call from a background thread. On the UI (or main) thread, you are not allowed to do such a time-consuming operation. For example, see the `AsyncTask` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [usage](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).